If $a$ and $b$ are real numbers such that $b-a=2\pi$ then equality $\sin\big[[a,b]\big]=[-1,1]=\cos\big[[a,b]\big]$ holds?
Let's we assume $a$ and $b$ are real numbers such that the equality
$$
b-a=2\pi
$$
holds: so I am trying to prove that restriction of sine and cosine functions on $[a,b]$ are surjective onto $[-1,1]$ proving that each one has there maximum and minimum so that by Intermediate value theorem the statement follows.
Now by the Archimedean property the set
$$
N:=\big\{n\in\mathbb N^+:a\le n\cdot(2\pi)\big\}
$$
is not empty (right?) so that let's we put
$$
\nu:=\min N
$$
So I observed the following implications
$$
2(\nu-1)\pi<a
\Rightarrow
2\nu\pi-2\pi<a
\Rightarrow
2\nu\pi-2\pi-b<a-b=-2\pi
\Rightarrow
2\nu\pi-b<0
\Rightarrow
2\nu\pi<b
$$
since $\nu$ is the least element of $N$: thus we conclude that the cosine function has maximum in $[a,b]$.
Now unfortunately I was not able to prove that cosine has minimum and I was not able to treat the sine function so that I thought to put here a specific question: could someone help me, please?

What do you mean by surjective onto $[0,1]$ into $[a,b]$?

Your language is hard to understand. Sine and cosine take negative values also on $[a,b]$.

What you want to show is that there exist $x_1,x_2\in[a,b]$ such that $\sin(x_1) = 0$ and $\sin(x_2) = 1$ and similarly for cosine. Of course, you know $\sin(\frac\pi 2+2k\pi) = 1$, so...

The condition $b-a=2\pi$ seems to imply that $[a,b]$ is the domain of the functions. But in that case the range is $[-1,1]$, not $[0,1]$.

Did you mean $[-1,1]$?  That still holds.  After all, for any $\alpha\in [-1,1]$ there exists $x\in [0,2\pi]$ such that $\sin x=\alpha$ (resp. $\cos x=\alpha$) and there is some integer $n$ such that $a≤x+2\pi,n≤b$.

@Lucenaposition I want prove that the restriction of sine and cosine in [a,b ] is a surjective function onto [0,1].

Antonio, that's simply wrong, for example, take $a = 0$ and $b = 2\pi$. The image is $[-1,1]$.

So the image of $[a,b]$ under $\sin$ or $\cos$ has $[0,1]$ as a subset right?

@Lucenaposition Yep! More clearly I am trying to prove the equality $$\sin\big[[a,b]\big]=[0,1]=\cos\big[[a,b]\big]$$ holds.

Antonio, I'll say it again, that's wrong, $\sin([a,b]) = [-1,1] = \cos([a,b])$, which is clear if you take $a = 0$ and $b = 2\pi$.

As people keep telling you, sine and cosine take negative values as well as positive.  Just consider $(a,b)=(0,2\pi)$.

@Lucenaposition, first of all, it's probably ordered pair, not interval. Secondly, that's completely irrelevant.

@Ennar Well, actually if $a=0$ and $b=1$ then $\sin(\pi/2)=1$ and $\sin(-\pi/2)=-1$, $\cos(0)=1$ and $\cos(\pi)=-1$ so that you are wrong.

I'm not sure what you mean by "actually", but yes, that's what we are all trying to tell you.

@Ennar I understand: by mistake I write $[0,1]$ and not $[-1,1]$, sorry. I edit the question.

By intermediate value theorem it is enough to show that there exist $x_1,x_2\in[a,b]$ such that $\sin(x_1) = -1$ and $\sin(x_2) = 1$, because from IVT it follows that $$[-1,1] = [\sin(x_1),\sin(x_2)]\subseteq \sin([\min\{x_1,x_2\},\max\{x_1,x_2\}]) \subseteq \sin([a,b]) \subseteq [-1,1]$$
which implies $\sin([a,b]) = [-1,1].$
I will show the existence of such $x_2$ and leave the existence of $x_1$ as exercise because it is completely analogous. Also, the same claim for $\cos$ is completely analogous.
Note that $\sin(\frac \pi 2+2k\pi) = 1$ for any integer $k$. Define $$A = \left\{k\in\mathbb Z\mid \frac\pi 2+2k\pi \geq a\right\}.$$
$A$ is bounded from bellow, so $\min A =: k_0$ exists. Let $x_2 = \frac\pi 2+2k_0\pi$. By our choice of $k_0$, $x_2 \geq a$. Also, $x_2 \leq b$, because $$x_2 > b \implies \frac\pi 2+2k_0\pi > a + 2\pi \implies \frac\pi 2+2(k_0-1)\pi > a\implies k_0-1\in A$$ which is contradiction with the minimality of $k_0$. Thus, $x_2\in [a,b]$ and $\sin(x_2) = 1$.

Hi, first of all thanks for the answer. Anyway, to prove the existence of $x_2$ in $[a,b]$ such that $\cos(x_2)=-1$ I tried to do what to follow as you suggested.
$$
A=\left{k\in\mathbb Z:a\le 2k\pi-\frac{\pi}{2}\right}
$$
$$
k_0:=\min A
$$
$$
x_2:=2k_0\pi-\frac{\pi}{2}
$$
$$
b\le x_2\Rightarrow a+2\pi\le2k_0\pi-\frac{\pi}{2}\Rightarrow a\le 2(k_0-1)\pi-\frac{\pi}{2}
$$
Is it correct? However unfortunately I was not able to prove the existence of $x_2$ such that $\cos(x_2)=-1$: what can you suggest about?

It seems I found what to follow.
$$
A=\left{k\in\mathbb Z:a\le 2k\pi-\pi\right}
$$
$$
k_0:=\min A
$$
$$
x_2:=2k_0\pi-\pi
$$
$$
b\le x_2\Rightarrow a+2\pi<2k_0\pi-\pi\Rightarrow a\le 2k_0\pi-3\pi=2k_0\pi-2\pi-\pi=2(k_0-1)\pi-\pi
$$
Is it correct?

@AntonioMariaDiMauro, your second comment is on the right track, however you are missing the conclusion. Do you understand the point of that series of implication, what are we proving?

In both cases we conclude that $x_2<b$ so that in the first we observe $\sin(x_2)=-1$ and in the second $\cos(x_2)=-1$, right? Now we actually prove that sine and cosine has maximum and minimum in $[a,b)$  so that the statement follows by intermediate value theorem, right?

@AntonioMariaDiMauro, correct.

Perfect, answer upvoted and approved: thanks very much for your assistance! :-)
